# Background image not display once published to server

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with several worksheets that each have a different background image. I can see them just fine on desktop but once published to tableau server, the background images are there. When the server was using v10.1 the images displayed just fine but now that it is in 10.2 it won't show. I have clicked on the button to include external files but still no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was a bug that was fixed in an update.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a packaged workbook? Saving as a twbx may do a better job of keeping the images along with it.

Comment: Yes it is a twbx file. When published to the tableau server it shows the excel file but I'm not sure if it should include the image files as well or just the data files.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to add background image from dashboard by clicking on image as :

```
 [Background image]
             https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRZKT.png
```

when you will publish it will remain on tableau server.